# How to optimize a EF Core Friendship System Model with Dual User References?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am currently working on designing a friendship system in EF Core. My current models draw significant inspiration from [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/135941/designing-a-friendships-database-structure-should-i-use-a-multivalued-column/135966#135966) provided to the question ["Designing a friendships database structure: Should I use a multivalued column?"](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/135941/designing-a-friendships-database-structure-should-i-use-a-multivalued-column) on Stack Exchange.

I find that the described data model introduces some complexity when attempting to use it in EF Core, particularly due to the dual user references.

```cs
public sealed class Friendship : EntityBase
{
    public User Requester { get; private set; } = null!;

    public User Addressee { get; private set; } = null!;

    // irrelevant properties, constructors, or methods...
}
```

As a result, a user must have two navigation properties for EF Core to accurately map the references.

```cs
public sealed class User : IdentityUser<Guid>
{
    private readonly List<Friendship> _friendshipsReceived = new();

    public IReadOnlyCollection<Friendship> FriendshipsReceived => _friendshipsReceived.AsReadOnly();

    private readonly List<Friendship> _friendshipsRequested = new();

    public IReadOnlyCollection<Friendship> FriendshipsRequested => _friendshipsRequested.AsReadOnly();

    // irrelevant properties, constructors, or methods...
}
```

In my view, this setup complicates analysis, requiring concatenation and sorting of the two lists at runtime repeatedly.

For instance, consider the following example query:

```cs
var result = _friendshipsReceived
    .Concat(FriendshipsRequested)
    .Where(f => f.GetLatestFriendshipStatus().Equals(FriendshipStatus.From(FriendshipStatusCode.Accepted)));
```

In this query, both FriendshipsReceived and FriendshipsRequested need to be concatenated and iterated. This is because a requested friendship could be accepted by the other user, and conversely, a received friendship could have been accepted by "me". Thus, we need to consider both lists to accurately determine the friendships with the latest status of "Accepted."

Is there an alternative approach you would recommend? Any assistance would be highly appreciated.

For a comprehensive view of the entire data model in the domain layer, please visit the following GitHub link: [Friendship System Domain Models](https://github.com/maik-hasler/FriendshipSystem/tree/main/src/Domain/Models/Friendships)

Comment: It is hard to represent graphs on a relational DB, you may want to check out the graph DBs too.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! I've never worked with NoSQL databases before and have primarily stuck to relational databases. I'd consider it as an excellent solution, even though it's not my primary approach at the moment. Out of interest it would be exciting to know if there is a suiting solution for relational databases aswell.

Comment: I don't see the need for the concatenation.  Each user has a collection of 'pendingFriendships` (before the request has been accepted), and another collection of 'acceptedFriendships` (when the request has been accepted).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a relatively simple variation to your schema that would work quite nicely. If you consider adding or removing friendships is something that happens fairly rarely, but retrieving a list of friends is very common - you simply create **two** friendship records one from each side of the friendship.

Your friendship class would look like this:

```
public class Friendship
{
    public User User { get; set; }

    public User Friend { get; set; }

    public bool IsRequester { get; set; }
}
```

then upon a friend request being made, you create two records where the `User` / `Friend` / `IsRequester` are reversed. You have to take a little extra effort to make sure your keep the two records in sync, but you still gain all of the benefits when it comes to data integrity and retrieval.

I'm a little rusty on my [EF attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys?tabs=data-annotations) but under the hood you still have a composite primary key made up of the two user ids. For the most common data retrieval pattern "Get me all my friends" for which the query criterion - the current user's id - also matches the first part of the primary key so will be very efficient. You also only need a single navigation property.

Comment: Is there a way to add a history of the friendship? E.g. "Requested", "Accepted", "Blocked" etc.? Would I have to maintain two records one from each side of the history?

Comment: You can have additional fields in the Friendship class quite easily, which would support the scenario user a has muted user b, but user b hasn't muted user a, so user b still sees all of user a's posts or whatever